# Delphi (XE) BPL Packages do not load: DevExpress, RemObjects

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe, remobjects

Good Day,

I am in the process of trying to open a legacy software project in Delphi XE. Whenever I try to open the IDE, I get around 100 - 110 error messages, one error message per DevExpress component not loading. This happens when I open the IDE itself AND when I open an existing project now.

The funniest part is that the paths to these BPLs are correct and all the "missing" BPL files are in those paths. The Environment variables point to these folders as well, and yet it just doesn't work. I attached a few pictures for ease of reference. You will notice the "missing" files in the Folder displayed in the screenshots. The BPLs are there, the paths are correct, but these modules just will not load...

What am I doing wrong? Why can't Delphi see these files and load them, even though these files are indeed present in those specified folders? Is there another setting I can try?

Thank you very much in advance!

Attached Images:
[image]

Comment: Most times the BPL packages has some co dependancys like dlls, or other BPL but your IDE will not show the BPL that is missing but only your BPL that you are trying to include. Try using Process Monitor and sniff what yout IDE is trying to load, you will find a File thats says "could not be found". Put it in the wanted location and you are done.

Comment: `What am I doing wrong?`  We don't know the history of this installation or how you went about installing those components in the first place.  The first thing to do would be to make a fresh install of XE then a fresh install of DevExpress and RemObjects.  That should "just work" and is usually easier than trying to fix whatever was broken by not doing it the right way in the first place.

Comment: The runtime BPL files are required by the design time BPL files that the IDE loads. Make sure the directory that contains them is on the system PATH and that it's not messed up / too long etc.

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of attempts, in the end it was necessary to completely remove both RemObjects as well as DevExpress, and then re-installing them one-by-one. Everything was fine after that.